# MS Access - Extract single value for calculation

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, nested

This an MS Access related question.

I get the Collateral divided 50 times because I have 50 rows in my ExchangeRates table... however the SELECT statement is supposed to only extract the value associated to CurrencyCode="EUR". How can I change the below statement to have the division being applied once only?

```
SELECT tbl_A.Security, tbl_A.Typ, Sum(([Collateral]/(SELECT tblExchangeRates.RateToUSD
FROM tblExchangeRates
WHERE (((tblExchangeRates.CurrencyCode)="EUR"))))) AS CollateralUSD
FROM tbl_A, tblExchangeRates
GROUP BY tbl_A.Security, tbl_A.Typ
HAVING (((tbl_A.Typ)="PR"));
```

Comment: Why is there no JOIN? Could you give some sample data and the result you expect to see?

Comment: @PaulFrancis, I am not sure a join is necessary there

Comment: JOIN makes your code more efficient and actually **could** eliminate the need for complications.

Comment: @paulFrancis, what's wrong with creating an alias table without a join as I did in my answer? Additionally, a join requires (as its name suggests it) that both tables would bear at least one similar value... which is not the case here as tbl_A does not bear any exchange rate data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is what I was willing to get, just an Alias. SQL gurus, you are welcome to review.

```
SELECT tbl_A.Security, Sum(([Collateral]/[RateToUSD])) AS CollateralUSD
FROM tbl_A, (SELECT RateToUSD
    FROM tblExchangeRates
    WHERE CurrencyCode = 'EUR')  AS MyAliasQ
GROUP BY tbl_A.Security
HAVING (((tbl_A.Typ)="PR"));
```